# ¿Cómo asignar la suma de una columna a una columna de otra tabla en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Cómo puedo hacer una sentencia que actualice el campo Balance de "Cuenta 1"  y ese resultado se sea igual al total de pagos que hay en la columna Monto, donde el IDcuenta sea 1 en la tabla Pagos?

```
SELECT SUM(Monto) FROM Pagos where IDcuenta=1;
```

Tabla 1= Pagos / Tabla 2= Cuenta / Tabla 3= Cliente

[image: TABLA PAGO]
[image: TABLA CUENTA]
[image: TABLA CLIENTE]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu update se puede simplificar

```
update cliente 
set 
    balance = (select sum(Monto) Monto from Pagos where idcliente = 1)
where idcliente = 1
```

En este caso, como es un solo idcliente es trivial.. si fueran para muchos clientes, igual podrias hacer algo asi, solo que tomarias el idcliente de la tabla cliente y sacarias el where...

```
update cliente c
set 
    balance = (select sum(Monto) Monto from Pagos where idcliente = c.id)
```